# Simple Java Loop Question

Tags: java

Assume that the  int variables  i and  j have been declared, and that  n has been declared and initialized.

Using  for loops (you may need more than one), write code that will cause a triangle of asterisks of size  n to be output to the screen.

For example, if the value of n is 4, the output should be

```
 *
 **
 ***
 ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're in school/college and more interested in getting some, more power to you buddy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Why would you give him the answers damn it! Your only hurting him!

Comment: It was stupid to post the full answer, but the down-vote is also for the smart aleck "getting some" remark.

Comment: If he/she's serious about programming, perhaps this snippet shall enlighten him. Besides, if he/she can't figure out something this basic he'll likely move on to better things (bricklaying, for example).

Comment: Well I had this already: for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
System.out.print("*");

but that wasnt doing the trick
}

Comment: @Mathew: I don't mind the downrate, I do hope for your sake you get a sense of humor someday however :)

Comment: @mohabitar, if you have partial code, you should always post it in the question.

Answer (score 9):

I won't do your homework, so here is a hint:

- The first line is always 1 element long.
- The last line is always N elements long.
- The are a total of N lines.

Surely, with the above, you can create the necessary program.

Comment: Well so obviously we have the answer below, but Im still not understanding how this code works exactly. So we start with i=0, then we go to the next loop where j=0 and j<=i, so we print one *. Now we do the loop again, so we increment i to 1, we increment j as well to 1, 1<=i(1) so we print another *. I dont understand how triangles begin to form?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun - single for-loop solution:

```
public void doIt(int n) {
  String temp = String.copyValueOf(char[n]);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    System.out.println(temp.substring(n-i).replace((char) 0, 'x'));
}
```

And some recursion - zero for-loop solution:

```
public void doItAgain(int n, String display) {
  if (n==0) return;
  System.out.println(display);
  doItAgain(n-1, display+'x');
}
```

(call it with `doItAgain(4,"x")` for your example)

Comment: Nice one. Fun indeed :D

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

```
public class loop1
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        { 
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
            System.out.print("*"); 
            System.out.println();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ForLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0;i <= 9;i++){
            for(int j = 1;j <= i;j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, easist way to do it using main method --> public static void main (Strings [] args){

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```